# How to compare a PS array with mongoDB to find deleted items?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, powershell

I am pulling a lot of AD objects with PS and dropping them into a MongoDB collection, using MDBC driver (https://github.com/nightroman/Mdbc). This created a collection with ca. 35000 documents.

The ps script will update the database if a users gets disabled or some attribute changes on AD.

But the problem appears when a users gets deleted from AD. I need to update that on MongoDB.

The approach so far, is pulling all data from Mongo and checking if there are in $ADUsers, which is the list I pulled from AD. Then, I update some fields on MongoDB. So, basically I am looping through an array of powershell and checking the DB.

```
$adusers = Get-ADUser -Filter * 

    Connect-Mdbc $connectionString Company Users
    $usersInDB = Get-MdbcData -As PS

    foreach ($userInDB in $usersInDB)
    {
        $result = $adusers.Where({ $_.id -eq $userInDB._id })
        if (-not $result)
        {
            Update-MdbcData -Query $query (New-MdbcUpdate -Set @{
                    ADEnabled         = $false;
                    Status        = "Deleted";
                })
        }
    }
```

Problem is that this is taking too long. Apparently, Powershell doesn't like me looping through all items, but I couldn't find a better way to do it.

So, do you know a better way to do it? Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Get all userprincipalnames from AD in one variable and all userprincipalnames from MongoDB in another variable. Then compare-object $ADPrincipals $MongoPrincipals gives you the result. You might want to filter out the upns in MongoDB that have already been deleted.